# Landscape/Portrait viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation

I have an app that works in landscape and portrait on the iPad.  I have code that animates some of the buttons, labels, etc. like the code below that bounces a button from the button up into place that is called when the view loads (viewDidLoad).

```
+ (void)bottomUpBounceIn:(UIView *)view {
    view.hidden = NO;
    JNWSpringAnimation *translate = [JNWSpringAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
    translate.damping = 30;
    translate.stiffness = 396.89;
    translate.mass = 3.6;
    translate.fromValue = @(600);
    translate.toValue = @(0);
    [view.layer addAnimation:translate forKey:translate.keyPath];
        view.hidden = NO;
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(view.transform, 0, 0);
}
```

Thing is...when the iPad is in landscape orientation the buttons DO NOT bounce in from the bottom up but from the site (portrait's bottom).

Anyone experience a similar problem? I notice my views load briefly in portrait orientation and then switch quickly to landscape. My segues are exhibiting the same behavior as well :(

Help! Thanks.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is too soon. The view isn't sized or orientated properly yet. Start your animation in `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: Gracias.  I actually did that and then checked the wrong part of my code (wrong view) and wondered why nothing had changed... womp womp. Thanks for giving me the confidence to go back and check my work.  All the best to you sir or madam :)

Comment: Yikes. Upon further inspection. I see my view controller is calling viewDidLoad twice for some reason :(

Comment: That can't be for the same instance of the view controller. You must be creating another instance.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm fairly new to ios dev but I thought I put a break point in my viewWillAppear method and the top of my stack said [HomeViewController viewWillAppear:] with each call... :(  If it helps this behavior doesn't happen upon launch, just when I navigate back to the home controller from another controller. Perhaps it's a segue issue? In fact my only use of a non-custom segue doesn't give me this problem... hmmm, btw big thanks for your time/consideration.